# GA4 Custom Channel Group Incompatible with Acquisition Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When a custom channel group is added to a traffic acquisition report all metrics are greyed out and displayed as 'incompatible'.

*Note: this is only an issue when creating a new report or editing a report.  Existing traffic acquisition reports that include custom channel groups work just fine.*

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a custom channel group (no actual modifications are needed, just create and save)
2. Go to 'Reports' > 'Library' > 'Create new report' > 'Create detail report'
3. Select 'Traffic acquisition' as template
4. Try to add a metric.  They will all be greyed out and display the 'incompatible metric' notification

When you create a custom channel grouping it is automatically included in the traffic acquisition template, which is what is causing the issue.  If you remove the custom channel group from the list of dimensions, then you'll be able to select all of the standard metrics as expected.  *Note: once you remove the custom channel group you won't be able to add it back!*

I've validated this on multiple properties.  What's frustrating is that dimension is clearly compatible with standard traffic acquisition metrics.  Any previously created reports work just fine with the custom channel group.  You just can't create new reports or edit existing reports once the custom channel group included.